# Как программно подсветить конкретную метку в коллекции ObjectManager с подсветкой соответствующего кластера Yandex API без перерисовки карты?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

#### Задача.

Вывожу на карту гостиницы в виде меток (Points) с группировкой их в коллекции ObjectManager.
С учетом начального масштаба многие одиночные метки объединены в кластеры.
При выборе пользователем нужной гостиницы в списке основного приложения - на карте необходимо подсветить выбор нужной точки, при этом, так как она скорее всего спрятана в кластер - то подсветить надо этот кластер, а также все кластеры, которые будут отображены при приближении к точке.
Есть предположение что изменение опции Preset как для точки, так и для кластера можно заложить в скрипт изначально. Условиями, привязанными к Events точки. Например, OnClick (?)
А при необходимости программно вызывать OnClick на объекте Point.
Пытался придумать решение по примерам отсюда:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_events/
Но опыта в JavaScript маловато и пока не очень получается.
Пожалуйста, подтолкните в нужном направлении.
Спасибо.


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


Всё объединил, всё теперь замечательно работает.

Вот тут конечный рабочий вариант: https://dropmefiles.com/S8ilr

За исключением одного момента: после того, как происходит программный выбор метки - иконка кластера не обновляется. С обновлением иконки кластера просто беда. В интернете все жалуются на отсутствие красивого штатного решения.

Я пошёл по простому пути. Повесил на кластер эвент "mouseenter", который при наведении курсора на кластер обновляет его иконку.
Осталось понять как программно вызвать это событие на кластере.

В файле с примером отметил то место, куда надо вставить программный вызов mouseenter и тогда у меня всё заработает.

**Пожалуйста, помогите решить.**

Я в миллиметре от финиша, но топчусь уже три дня... никак не получается, хотя и в руководстве API вроде есть нужный метод  fire, вот только ни одного примера нет а сам сделать не могу - не выходит.

Заранее спасибо.

Поясню как всё работает. Внизу список меток (не всех, а только первых 10-ти). При нажатии на элемент этого списка на карте происходит выбор метки, окрашивание её в другой цвет и позиционирование карты на этой метке. При этом, если выбранная метка входит в кластер, то иконка кластера также должна покраситься в другой цвет. В принципе это и происходит, но чтобы это увидеть надо сделать зум (туда-сюда). Лишний зум в моём случае недопустим. Поэтому я сделал эвент, который также раскрашивает иконку кластера. То есть после выбора метки из списка, если она в кластере, то чтобы увидеть выделенный кластер надо на него навести мышку. А если потом выбрать другую метку, то чтобы поменять выбранный кластер надо мышкой навести как на предыдущий выбранный так и на текущий выбранный кластер.

Answer (score 0):

Как определить, в каком кластере (если в нём) находится объект, описано в примере "[Открытие балуна кластера с выбранным объектом](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_balloon_open)". Как изменить свойства такого кластера – в другом примере "[Изменение цвета кластеров и меток при наведении](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_icon_hover)".

Если у вас не получается объединить эти примеры с менеджером объектов и коллекциями, соберите минимальный пример и приложите его к вопросу для анализа.

Comment: Сможете помочь? Я написал про всё, что у меня получилось в теме.